# If list item is in string, do something with that particular item and disregard rest of string

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

I have a list of items and I am searching for any one of those items in one large string. How can I call just the the item that was found?

Right now, I can search for the list items but I am returning the entire string, not just the list item I am searching for. For example:

```
my_list = ['foobar', 'lorem ipsum', 'hello world!']
my_string = 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.'

if any(list_item in my_string for list_item in my_list):
 print my_string
```

This returns the entire string, as expected, but how do I get only the keyword I was searching for? I not only need to know if the string contains one of the words, but which word it contains. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension as follows:

```
b = [list_item for list_item in my_list if list_item in my_string]

for i in b:
    print i

[OUTPUT]
lorem ipsum
```

Alternatively, you could print out the matches while looping through the `my_list`:

```
for i in my_list:
    if i in my_string:
        print i

[OUTPUT]
lorem ipsum
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> my_list = ['foobar', 'lorem ipsum', 'hello world!']
>>> my_string = 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.'
>>> [item for item in my_list if item in my_string]
['lorem ipsum']
```

Comment: +1 since you had the same solution, just a few seconds later.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this:

```
[list_item for list_item in my_list if list_item in my_string]
```

is the `in` operator will match even if the substring is only a partial word:

```
>>> "is" in "isn't"
True
```

Therefor:

```
my_list = ['foobar', 'lorem ipsum', 'mylorem ipsum', 'hello world!']
my_string = 'mylorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.'
print [list_item for list_item in my_list if list_item in my_string]
# ['lorem ipsum', 'mylorem ipsum']
```

Which may or may not be what you expect.

To fix this, use a regex:

```
>>> bool(re.search(r'\bis\b', "isn't"))
False
>>> bool(re.search(r'\bis\b', " tra la  is"))
True
```

If you want to limit yourself to complete matches (ie, `'lorem ipsum'` only matches that exact word string and not `'mylorem ipsum'`) you can use a regex:

```
import re

my_list = ['foobar', 'lorem ipsum', 'mylorem ipsum', 'hello world!']
my_string = 'mylorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.'

print [s for s in my_list if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(s), my_string)]
# ['mylorem ipsum']
```

Comment: +1 For a good point. Fortunately for me, I actually want to match partial words in my case.